# Azure Function doesn't follow CRON timer schedule

Tags: azure, triggers, timer, cron, azure-functions

I have a fair bit of experience with Azure Functions and I've never noticed had issue before, but a timer function I currently use is causing me a bit of a headache.

I use the CRON expression: `0 */18 * * * *` which to me means "run every 18 minutes". Generally it follows that pattern but recently it has developed a mind of its own. I write to Application Insights when it is invoked and these are the minutes between each invocation the other day:

18, 4, 4, 16, 18, 18, 6, 4, 14, 18, 18, 6, 9, 9, 18, 18, 6, 13, 18, 18, 18, 6, 16, 4.

Obviously, I expect them to all be 18, but it looks like it's like this every day. Some invocations happen as soon as 2 minutes after. I checked the status config at one point to see what it says and this was the contents:

```
{"Last":"2023-07-20T10:54:00.0084847+00:00","Next":"2023-07-20T11:00:00+00:00","LastUpdated":"2023-07-20T10:54:00.0084847+00:00"}
```

As you can see it ran and 10:54:00 and then scheduled the next to run at 11:00:00. Not exactly 18 minutes!

Extra info - the scheduled action takes about 3 minutes to run and the timeout is set to 10 minutes, but it never reaches that. I also deploy the Azure Function using Visual Studio as a Zip deploy. The Function App is runtime version 4.

Comment: The Azure function timer trigger uses a `6 part` expression called NCRONTAB, it also supports usual five part expression.  Even if that is not an issue, check other things like `time zone` set for your function app, whether _sampling_ is enabled, etc, refer this [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Investigating-and-reporting-issues-with-timer-triggered-functions-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the same CRON expression `0 */18 * * * *`:

[image]

Only one execution was irregular, and all other executions were regular with 18 minutes difference.

[image]

The irregularity in executions could be because of the function app is scaling out to multiple instances, and only one instance of the timer-triggered function is running across all instances.

- Check if there are any errors or exceptions that could be causing the function to fail, and the timer trigger doesn't retry after a function fails.
- Re-validate the configuration of your function app and ensure that it is set up correctly. Additionally, you can investigate the
- Try to test the function with different CRON expression (Ex: 5min [0 */5 * * * *]).
- As @*Anand Sowmithiran* mentioned, validate *timezone* of your function app.

If still the issue persists, try using a Timespan value instead of a CRON expression to specify the time interval between each function invocation.

As mentioned in the [document](https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/), to maintain **regular frequency** in function execution:

- Need to follow the below mentioned pattern while configuring CRON expressions:

[image]